# With askopenfilename delete the options (open, close) at the end

Tags: python, tkinter

Using `askopenfilename` I have opened the directory. 
But, I do not want to open the file, I would need it, just to see the files present in that particular path.
I want to see the path folder content after clicking the button in the frame.
Not only to see the content in the path but also to move back and fro too.
So I would like to delete the options (Datename, open, close) at the end.

Is there anyway I can solve the problem.

Here is my used code:
 f1 = Frame(root)
for frame in (f1):
frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

```
frame1 = ttk.LabelFrame(f1, text="Data")
frame1.grid(row=1, column=5, padx=(30,10), pady=(10,0), columnspan=2)  
b01 = ttk.Button(frame1, text="New", compound = "left", width=12, command=Dir_Data)
b01.grid(row=4, column=5, padx=20, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)                                                                

def Dir_Data():                                                                                             
    directory = "C:\Req_file\date_files"                                                                 
    temp = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir=directory)
```

Comment: please show what you have tried

Comment: So you basically want to show the content of a directory in a window?

Comment: yes@ toti08., I have used directory =  "C:\Req_file\Date_files"                           
 temp = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir=directory)

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: Why not showing the content in a another widget? You could use for example a `tkmessageBox` or a `Message` box.

Comment: I have created the frame and a labelframe inside the frame. So, inside the label frame I have inserted a button. By clicking the button, i want to open and see the content of the given path but not opening the files in that path. I have used the command in the ttk.Button, and have defined inside the command name.

Comment: @Vishali can you post your code? Just to have a bit more of context...

Comment: I have posted in my question that i have used

Comment: What is `f1` in your code? Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: There is no way to customize the `askopenfilename` dialog the way you want. You need to show the content of your directory in another widget, like a `ttk.Treeview` .

Comment: Not only to show the content of the directory but also moving back and fro to other folders too. So, I am afraid whether I can use the ttk.Treeview

Comment: The formatting of your code is messed up.

Comment: I work with the huge code. so I have posted only the part which is related to the question

Comment: Yes, but it does not show properly in the question. Can you please fix it @Vishali?

Comment: I would like to know if I can use other than askopenfilename to find my solution if it is not possible to solve using the askopenfilename

Comment: Thanks a lot for everyone I used os.startfile(directory) instead of askopenfile